# I cannot select element using Id?

Tags: javascript, html, express, dom, ejs

I am trying to pass id as an argument to a function like this,

**Html**

```
<button type="button" class="like btn" onclick="like('<%=postid%>')">       
            <svg  id ='<%=likeid%>' class="bi bi-heart" width="3em" height="3em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2.748l-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
              </svg>
    </button>
```

and then trying to select this id like this,

```
function like(id){
      var e=document.getElementById(id);
      console.log(e)

  }
```

but it returns `null` in console, so i tried doing,

```
window.onload=()=>{
  function like(id){
      var e=document.getElementById(id);
      console.log(e)

  }
}
```

now I am getting an error that `function like is not defined`
I have been trying different things from 2 days but nothing works,I have also tried moving the script tag at the end of body tag,I have also tried selecting the element using jquery ,but even that cannot select the element,please someone tell me how do I solve this.

Comment: Try to console <%=postid%> and check is its value is ok or not , i many times found that the issue is with ejs variables

Comment: yes I tried Its ok

Answer (score 1):

did you something like this :

```
const like = (id) => {
    const e = document.getElementById(id);
    console.log(e);
};
```

and the you can call the function

```
like('my-id');
```

Comment: that still returns null

Answer (score 1):

You can pass id like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function like(id)
            {
                console.log(id);
                console.log(document.getElementById(id));
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button type="button" class="like btn" onclick="like('someid')">       
            <svg  id ='someid' class="bi bi-heart" width="3em" height="3em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2.748l-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
              </svg>
    </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want to import external javascript file with `like` function, you can simply do this when your `script.js` file and `html` file are:

```js
function like(id)
{
    console.log(id);
    console.log(document.getElementById(id));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button type="button" id="buttonId" class="like btn" onclick="like('someid')">       
            <svg id ="someid" class="bi bi-heart" width="3em" height="3em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2.748l-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
              </svg>
    </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had done the same thing,do you mean that I should keep the code in the same html file inside a script tag?

Comment: Is your function in another js file? If yes, there is another solution. The code needs not keep in same html file. But you can call the function like this. That's why I wrote it in same file.

Comment: yes it is in other file,and it is exactly how you've written it,thanks for help anyways

Comment: Bro, can I suggest you another solution?

Comment: actually Ive changed my mind and I am doing something else,but Id like to hear your solution as well just,In case someone would need it.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look tommorow